Unit test effect in Angular
I am using Angular signal and to execute change in signal using effect function.
How to mock signal to trigger effect during unit test.
import { effect, Injector, Signal } from '@angular/core';

export const chainEffect = (initialEffectFn: () => void): EffectChainer => {
  return {
    configure: ({ delay, trigger, injector }) => ({
      run: (effectFn): void => {
        initialEffectFn();

        const destroyRef = effect(
          () => {
            if (delay()) {
              return;
            } else if (trigger()) {
              effectFn();
              destroyRef.destroy();
            } else {
              destroyRef.destroy();
              throw new Error('error');
            }
          },
          { injector },
        );
      },
    }),
  };
};



export type EffectChainer = {

  configure: (config: {
    delay: Signal<boolean>;
    trigger: Signal<boolean>;
    injector: Injector;
  }) => ChainedEffect;
};


export type ChainedEffect = {
  run: (effect: () => void) => void;
};

I tried with below approach but not able to go inside effect() with signal value
it('should run effect function if trigger signal is true', () => {
    let delay = signal<boolean>(false);
    let trigger = signal<boolean>(false);
     
    const chainer: EffectChainer = chainEffect(initialEffectFn);

    const chainedEffect: ChainedEffect = chainer.configure({ delay, trigger, injector });

    expect(()=>chainedEffect.run(effectFn)).toThrowError('error');
  
  });

